# vspace to half empty space

Tags: spacing

How do I insert some text in exactly the vertical middle of the remainder of a page?
Something like `\vspace{0.5\fill}`

The following MWE currently adds the text to the end of the page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\vfill
\centering{END OF DOCUMENT}
\end{document}
```

Comment: add another \vfill after the text.

Comment: Or use `\vfil` instead of `\vfill` because TeX insert `\vfil` automatically on the end of outputted page.

Comment: `\centering` does not take an argument so the braces in  `\centering{END OF DOCUMENT}`  are not doing anything. (or course as it's the end , it doesn't  matter that the rest of the document is centred but it looks odd in the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fill before and after. Of course, if the “end of document” doesn't fit the page, you will get an almost empty new page.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\vspace*{\fill}
{\centering END OF DOCUMENT\par\nopagebreak}
\vspace*{\fill}

\end{document}
```

Comment: how does one calculate the space after \lipsum to end of page  -  idea was to then get the midway point and use tikz to insert text